# MinGW Debian. Cross compiling win64 project with freeglut "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

I have simple (sample) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //Needed for "exit" function

//Include OpenGL header files, so that we can use OpenGL
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

//Called when a key is pressed
void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, //The key that was pressed
                int x, int y) {    //The current mouse coordinates
switch (key) {
    case 27: //Escape key
        exit(0); //Exit the program
    }
}

//Initializes 3D rendering
void initRendering() {
    //Makes 3D drawing work when something is in front of something else
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

//Called when the window is resized
void handleResize(int w, int h) {
    //Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective

    //Set the camera perspective
    glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the camera
    gluPerspective(45.0,                  //The camera angle
               (double)w / (double)h, //The width-to-height ratio
               1.0,                   //The near z clipping coordinate
               200.0);                //The far z clipping coordinate
}

//Draws the 3D scene
void drawScene() {
    //Clear information from last draw
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
    glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates

    //Trapezoid
    glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, -5.0f);

    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //Begin triangle coordinates

    //Pentagon
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);

    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);

    //Triangle
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, -5.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, -5.0f);

    glEnd(); //End triangle coordinates

    glutSwapBuffers(); //Send the 3D scene to the screen
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400); //Set the window size

    //Create the window
    glutCreateWindow("Basic Shapes - videotutorialsrock.com");
    initRendering(); //Initialize rendering

    //Set handler functions for drawing, keypresses, and window resizes
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);

    glutMainLoop(); //Start the main loop.  glutMainLoop doesn't return.
    return 0; //This line is never reached
}
```

As you can see, this code is from a tutorial, which normally compiles fine, and until I start messing around with cross compiling it does. But when I try to compile it with:

```
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall -o basicshapes.exe main.cpp -lfreeglut -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin
```

I get list of errors like:

```
/tmp/cczfJtsd.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `__imp_glEnable'
(...several more gl func similar errors)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I really don't have any idea what is wrong. It's my first time with cross compilation and I don't yet completely get it.
I've installed MinGW from synaptic and freeglut from this link:

http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/

I tried to compile it myself, but I was unable to do that so I just copy/paste installed it from this package.

Comment: Where is `libfreeglut.a`? I suspect not in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin`

Comment: no, its in     lib folder
and btw, permissions are rwx r-x-r-x for both folder bin, and freeglut.dll

Comment: The error suggests g++ can't find `libfreeglut.a`. The `-L` flag specifices additional directories for g++ to search for libraries. You wouldn't typically expect to find them in a bin directory like `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin`. You probably need to modify the argument to point to your `lib` folder containing `libfreeglut.a`

Comment: did that, didn't work :/ 
But I've downloaded a 'glu32.dll    glut32.dll    opengl32.dll' from
http://mycodelog.com/2010/05/15/gllibs/ paste it into compilation folder and ran comand:
'x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall -o basicshapes.exe main.cpp -lfreeglut  glu32.dll glut32.dll opengl32.dll'
and i get an *.exe file, that doesn't work. Windows shows:
*.exe is not a valid Win32 Application.
Is that due to 32/64 bit incompatibility? I gues this libs, ale 32 bit, and if so...
Why then 
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ * 
compilation gaves me this:
http://pastebin.com/dsDYuQrp
similar but not quite

Comment: answering to my own question...
freeglut.dll is only a front-end of OpenGL, so to work (and compile) properly it needs to have 3 additional files  glu32.dll glut32.dll opengl32.dll
The trick is that even they called *32.dll they might be 64bit version, you/I  need to download corect ones, and my erros was becouse I was using 32bit versions, of them, when i obtained 64bit ones, everything ran smoothly...
Thanks for help anyway ;)